# POST request taking longer than timeout causing duplicates

Tags: ios, tcp, network-programming, duplicates, alamofire

I have an iOS application where I `POST` transactions to an API each time a transaction is completed. Once I get a `200 response code` from the server I update an attribute on the transaction:

```
newTransaction.Synced = true
```

Incase the network connection ever drops I also `POST` every transaction where `Synced = false` when Reachability detects a network connection.

In perfect network conditions this works wells. However when I enable the Network Link Conditioner on my iPad and set packet loss to say 40% I start to see duplicated transactions on my server. What I assumed was happening is that it was taking longer than 30 seconds (the client side timeout on the request) to send my request and get the response from the server due to the high packet loss.

To confirm this, I made my API Sleep for 40 seconds for each web request and disabled Network Link Conditioner. As expected, the iOS app **never** set the `Synced` attribute to `true` as it was timing out before it got the response. However the server still created the entity for each `POST` request that was generated each time the iOS app launched or got network connectivity.

What's the best way to handle this situation so that duplicates never occur? I did think of adding a GUID to the transaction and then coding the API not to re-add the transaction if the GUID already exists. However the flip side is the iOS app would still never know the transaction has successfully synced. Is there a better way to handle this? Perhaps a timeout on the request which the server also adheres to?

Answer (score 0):

Your Idea of assigning the GUID to transaction is good, but you might need to maintain a table on client side (browser memory) which will hold a record of all the calls you made to server and never heard back.